# Web front-end for SQL Server Database Mail

Tags: sql-server, email

SQL Server 2005 introduced [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx) for sending e-mail messages from the SQL Server Database Engine in a robust fashion. Database Mail comes with a number of interesting [views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188023.aspx) like `sysmail_allitems`, `sysmail_sentitems`, `sysmail_faileditems`, `sysmail_unsentitems`, `sysmail_mailattachments` and `sysmail_event_log`. Is there any known stand-alone and friendly web front-end (preferably in ASP.NET) on top of these views that can be used by administrators (and ideally also users) for trouble-shooting and monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.  You can query the DMVs manually to view the data within them.  Setting up any sort of pretty interface wouldn't be of much use as you can't do anything with those DMVs besides look at them.

Database mail is a pretty robust system.

What specific issues are you trying to troubleshoot?

Comment: See my comments on Sam's answer for that kind of issues where an interface could help with some initial analysis without needing to pull up SQL Management Studio and querying views manually.

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of.  What kind of users would be poking around in the back-end - what would they be doing?  Once things are set up, the mail process seems to run pretty smoothly.  Are you having frequent problems?

Comment: The idea is to enable some simple checking. For example, users may complain that they are not receiving e-mails when in actual fact the system may have dispatched them yet the junk mail filter on the client-end blocking. A front-end can enable an admin to quickly verify this.

Comment: Another case would be that the application actually has a bug and not dispatched an automated e-mail notification when it was meant to go out.

Comment: Yet another example would be to simply check on failed sends via the sysmail_faileditems view.